# Ruby on Rails: undefined method, error with Controller methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, controller

I'm making a website where the user can input data into a database, and then can search the database on another page. At the moment the create new entry form works fine, and so does the search page for displaying the tables, as I haven't implemented the search yet.

Controller:

```
def search
 @project_search = Project.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
end

  private

   def sort_column
    Project.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "project_name"
   end

   def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
   end


def create
@project = Project.new(params[:project])


@project.client = params[:new_client] unless params[:new_client].blank?
@project.exception_pm = params[:new_exception_pm] unless params[:new_exception_pm].blank?
@project.project_owner = params[:new_project_owner] unless params[:new_project_owner].blank?
@project.role = params[:new_role] unless params[:new_role].blank?
@project.industry = params[:new_industry] unless params[:new_industry].blank?
@project.business_div = params[:new_business_div] unless params[:new_business_div].blank?

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

When I comment out the search method, my input form then works, but when they are both there, I get this error.

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted Source, from my form view at line 1:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
```

I think it's just a small problem, but I can't see how to fix it. I am new to ruby on rails, so go easy :).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure, but I think it's because of where `private` is located. In Ruby, everything after that call will be private. Rails may ignore your definition of create and use its own. Any chance you are commenting out `private` when you say you "comment out the search method"?

Comment: That was the problem. I removed the `private`. Did I really need it? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: You most probably need it, it just has to be at the end because everything after it is being considered as private.

Comment: @JamesMcL13 I would put any sort of controller helper methods below private (ie sort_column). As you get more experience with Rails and Ruby, you'll figure out what should be private, where methods should go etc. I think you're definitely on the right track and you'll figure these things out with experience.